# Undefined variable x search engine with mysql

Tags: php

I've made a search page, now it finally works, but it still gives the errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: x in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\horsemask\search.php on line 21
>   Notice: Undefined variable: construct in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\horsemask\search.php on line 23

I do use localhost, I don't know if thats the problem. It still gives hits and it works, but it looks ugly...
here is my code:

```
<?php

$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$search = $_GET ['search']; 

if(!$button)
echo "you didn't submit a keyword";
else
{
if(strlen($search)<=1)
echo "Search term too short";
else{
echo "Jou zoekterm <b>$search</b> leverde dit op: <hr size='1'></br>";
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("search");

$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
$x++;
if($x==1)
$construct .="keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
$construct .="AND keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";

}

$construct ="SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE $construct";
$run = mysql_query($construct);

$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

if ($foundnum==0)
echo "Er is niks gevonden op de zoekterm <b>$search<b>. Probeer een andere zoekterm.";
else
{
echo "$foundnum results found !<br>";

while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
{
$title = $runrows ['title'];
$desc = $runrows ['description'];
$url = $runrows ['url'];

echo "
<a href='$url'><b>$title</b></a><br>
$desc<br>
<a href='$url'>$url</a><p>
";

}
}

}
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you do any research?

Comment: yes, i tried it and it worked fine on localhost, but i still see the errors

Comment: define `$x`before incrementing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined variable `$x` and `$construct` anywhere but are trying to increment it (`$x++;`), so just create a variable like `$x = 0;` and `$construct = '';` before you're going to increment it.

Comment: THNX! that one worked, but i still have the other error

Comment: Define Construct too.

Comment: @EsliStavenga You don't have to use caps lock for that, also do you understand why you have to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize the variables before you use it like this:

(If you not initialize your variables it's trying to increment 'undefined' and it's trying to append a string to 'undefined', which clearly isn't going to work)

```
$x = 0;
$construct  = "";

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each) {

    $x++;
    if($x == 1)
        $construct .="keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    else
        $construct .="AND keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";

}
```

Also why you may see the errors on your sever but not on localhost is because error reporting is turn on/ off.

I would recommend you to turn on error reporting only in staging with:

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do operations on variables `$x` and `$construct` before initializing any value.

You should add something like `$x = 0` and `$construct = ''` in the code somewhere before.

Answer (score 0):

Correction code:

```
<?php

$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$search = $_GET ['search']; 

if(!$button)
echo "you didn't submit a keyword";
else
{
if(strlen($search)<=1)
echo "Search term too short";
else{
echo "Jou zoekterm <b>$search</b> leverde dit op: <hr size='1'></br>";
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("search");

$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

$x = 0;
$construct = '';

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
$x++;
if($x==1)
$construct .="keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
$construct .="AND keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";

}

$construct ="SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE $construct";
$run = mysql_query($construct);

$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

if ($foundnum==0)
echo "Er is niks gevonden op de zoekterm <b>$search<b>. Probeer een andere zoekterm.";
else
{
echo "$foundnum results found !<br>";

while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
{
$title = $runrows ['title'];
$desc = $runrows ['description'];
$url = $runrows ['url'];

echo "
<a href='$url'><b>$title</b></a><br>
$desc<br>
<a href='$url'>$url</a><p>
";

}
}

}
}

?>
```